# Postgres: Convert non-partitioned table to partitioned with a bit downtime

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have a non-partitioned table `record` which is append-only and I intended to partition it by range of `created` timestamp column using postgres native partition. (one partition per month)

I can tolerate a bit of downtime, so my plan is:

1. Create new table `record_partitioned` with partitions; copy all past month’s data into new partitioned table
2. Stop write into the table, copy current month’s data into new partitioned table (a bit of downtime)
3. Rename old table as `record_archived`, and rename new table as `record`
4. Resume write into table

Does this make sense?

Comment: What is the goal of partitioning here? Make it easier to delete old data?

Comment: For easy delete and improve performance because I usually only need to query latest partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work, but you can also consider the following:

- create a new partitioned table
- add a partition for the current month
- attach the existing large table as a partition for all past data
- once all data in the existing table have expired, drop it